# Swift: Instance member cannot be used on type

Tags: swift2, singleton

I'm trying to call a variable from my `Users` class in `Data` class but I'm thrown this error

> Instance member 'user' cannot be used on type 'Data'

`Data` class code:

```
import Foundation

class Data {

   static let sharedInstance = Data()

   let user = Users()
   var id = (user.userId).string

   //Login.swift
   static let quarterlyEndpoint: String = "http://anyapi/api/users/\(id)/quarterly/tasks"

// for prevent from creating this class object
private init() { }

}
```

`Users` class code:

```
var userId: Int {

    guard let  _userId = getId() else {
        return 0
    }

    return _userId
}
```

**UPDATE**

I can call the function but when I print my `weeklyEnd` I would get `http://anyapi/api/users/(Function)/quarterly/tasks` instead of `http://anyapi/api/users/3/quarterly/tasks`

```
let user = Users()

func getId() -> String
{
    let id = String(user.userId)
    return id
}

static let weeklyEndpoint: String = "http://anyapi/api/users/\(getId)/quarterly/tasks"
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
import Foundation

class Data {

static let sharedInstance = Data()

let user = Users()
let id:String?
let weeklyEndpoint: String?

// for prevent from creating this class object
private init() {
    id   = String((user.userId))
    //Login.swift
    weeklyEndpoint = "http://anyapi/api/users/\(id)/quarterly/tasks"
}

}
```

I'm having trouble calling my `weeklyEndPoint` from outside the `Data` class. I've tried `Data.weeklyEndPoint` but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a method inside the Data class like this .

```
func getusrid ()-> String
{
 var id = (user.userId).string
return id ;

}
```

You cannot get value from instance variable outside any method

EDIT:

```
class Data {

    static let sharedInstance = Data()
    let id:String?
    let quarterlyEndpoint: String?

    let user = Users()
  private init()
   {
     id   = String((user.userId))
     quarterlyEndpoint = "http://anyapi/api/users/\(id)/quarterly/tasks"

    }




}
```

Comment: How do I call it from the string? I've tried adding `\(getusrid())` but I would get an "Use of instance member 'getusrid' on type 'Data'; did you mean to use a value of type 'Data' instead?" error

Comment: Oh yes that will be a problem right , the best i can suggest is use your private init (){ id = (user.userId).string         quarterlyEndpoint: String = "http://anyapi/api/users/\(id)/quarterly/tasks"     
 }

Comment: and declare  the id and the quarterlyEndpoint variables earlier

Comment: Turns out I'm able to call it but my print output is `(Function)` instead of `3` (see updated post) Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: No this ain't function calling  it is just saying to you that getusrid is a (Function).

Comment: Oh I see.. I'm now getting an `Instance member "weeklyEndpoint" cannot be used on type "Data"` error when calling weeklyEndpoint from outside the `Data` class.. (For example, with `Data.weeklyEndpoint`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113110/discussion-between-sourav-sachdeva-and-noobdev).